# cannot implicitly convert type An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: .net-core, .net-6.0

```vbnet
public async Task<ServiceResponse> UploadFiles(UploadFilesRequest request)
{
    var isPo = false;
    var datas = await _respository.FindAllAysnc<PoEntity>();
    
    if (request.BucketName == "upload-do-file")
    {
        isPo = true;
        datas = await _respository.FindAllAysnc<DoEntity>();
    }

    ....
}
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDZpr.png)

I am trying to store PoEntity if isPo is true and store the DoEntity if isPo is false. However, I face the error of

> cannot implicitly convert type 'system.collections.generic.IEnumerable<Be.Domain.Entities.InvoiceData.DoEntity>' to
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Be.Domain.Entities.InvoiceData.PoEntity>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

while trying to do so. May I please ask what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you mean `PoEntity` or `DoEntity` - you have both. Typo?

Comment: Hi, i have both. PoEntity and DoEntity.

Answer (score 0):

You instantiate `datas` to have type `IEnumerable<DoEntity>` on this line,

```
var datas = await _respository.FindAllAysnc<PoEntity>();
```

Then you attempt to assign `IEnumerable<PoEntity>` to `datas`, on this line,

```
datas = await _respository.FindAllAysnc<DoEntity>();
```

They are not compatible types.

---

If, as you say, there is no relationship between `PoEntity` and `DoEntity`, you could  split implementations into two separate private methods.

```
private async Task<ServiceResponse> UploadFilesPo()
{
    var datas = await _respository.FindAllAysnc<PoEntity>();
    ...
}
```

and,

```
private async Task<ServiceResponse> UploadFilesDo()
{
    var datas = await _respository.FindAllAysnc<DoEntity>();
    ...
}
```

. Then change `UploadFiles` to,

```
public Task<ServiceResponse> UploadFiles(UploadFilesRequest request)
{
    if (request.BucketName == "upload-do-file")
    {
        return UploadFilesDo();
    }

    return UploadFilesPo();
}
```

Comment: may i ask what is the right approach to achieve my goal?

Comment: @Jingc, are `PoEntity` and `DoEntity` related in some way?

Comment: Hi, nope it is not

Comment: @Jingc, I extended my answer.